# How to enable row selection on UniGrid in BizFormEditData.ascx?

Tags: kentico

I am trying to enable multi-select on the UniGrid in the BizFormEditData.ascx web user control:

```
~/CMSModules/BizForms/Controls/BizFormEditData.ascx
```

I have tried enabling this via the code-in-front UniGrid definition:

```
<GridOptions ShowSelection="true" />
```

I have tried enabling this via the code-behind in the Page_Load method:

```
gridData.GridOptions.ShowSelection = true;
```

In either case, when I build the project and review, the selection column never appears which leads me to believe something else is interfering with that definition.

Any ideas?

Edited to add: this is on version 7

Comment: What Kentico version do you use?

Comment: @mivra thanks for pointing that out, I should have included that in the original question (I have edited it).  We are using version 7.

Comment: Strange. On my instance it's working without a problem = in CMS desk there is a checkbox column on the left side when I enter Data tab. I've also tried to install fresh Kentico 7 and it also works. You may yet try to set `SelectionColumn` property, but otherwise it would have to be either some customization on your side or a bug in a particular hotfix.

Comment: @mivra interesting, I know that the previous developer on this project had done some customization for filtering however I don't see anything immediately that jumps out at me that would suppress that field, but I'll go down that path a little further and see if there is something I missed.  Thanks for confirming that you can see it.  So far setting SelectionColumn = true has no affect, which leads me to believe it could be overridden somewhere else.

Comment: `SelectionColumn` is not a bool property. It tells what is the name of the column which contains identifier values - typically some ID column.

Comment: You are correct, that was a mistake in my comment--I was referring to setting the ShowSelection flag on the UniGrid GridOptions to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods outlined in my question are a correct way to enable this feature.

The issue I ran into is that a custom filter that had been written by another developer was dynamically generating an XML string and setting it to the `GridName` property of the `UniView` control.

This was overriding any of the methods above, resulting in the behavior I was struggling with.

So from a troubleshooting perspective:

1. Look at the `UniGrid` in the code-in-front to see if `<GridOptions ShowSelection="true"/>`  has been defined.
2. Look in the code-behind and see if the `GridOptions` are defined in the `Page_Load` method
3. Look to see if the `GridName` property is being set anywhere